# Switch to LockScreen

Tags: android, lockscreen

My application has a function that requires to return to LockScreen after pushing a button. Is there any way to switch to LockScreen automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can recall LockScreen by calling recreateMe() call back function in KeyguardStatusViewManager

> mCallback.recreateMe(null);

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

For locking,

```
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

and for disable lock,

```
lock.disableKeyguard()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want showing lockscreen when after pushing button?
If you want this, I will help you.
I tried this, finally I could this.
First, button's onClickEvent is doing sleep.
After then, you try turn on screen your device.

First,

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = ( DevicePolicyManager )getSystemService( DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE ); 
dpm.lockNow();
```

this code make your device go to sleep for lock.
after,

```
wake = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "wakeLock");
wake.acquire();
wake.release();
```

this code make turn on screen your device.
This link help you.
[How to call android default LockScreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191334/how-to-call-android-default-lockscreen)
you can try it!