# How to call android default LockScreen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

How to call android's default LockScreen in activity or service?

I create android application what is like a Optimus G2's knock on function.
But I have some problem.
My Activity has `OnStop()` or `OnDestroy()` function, i won't it's call default `LockScreen` or Sleep and wake.
First, I try `PowerManager.gotoSleep()`, but it's Android system API. Solution is `DevicePolicyManager` but I won't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the Device Administration API: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#top

When admin, you can use the Device Policy Manager and `lockNow()` to lock the screen: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29

To unlock, you have to use the windowmanager to add a flag to the current window.

```
WindowManager windowManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(windowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

To turn your screen on:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManagernewWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "wakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Don't forget the WAKE_LOCK permission in your manifestfile.

Comment: I try use device administration api, so i have sleep my phone.  
But I don't know how screen on my Phone.  
Do you know it?

Comment: Calling "lockNow()" from the Device Policy Manager should to the trick.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I called "lockNow()", phone is screen off and lock. But I don't know how to auto screen turn on. I set DevicePolicyManager.setMaximumTimeToLock(ComponentName, msTime) but it  doesn't work I want. I has someting wrong.

Comment: Ok, so you managed to lock it and want to unlock it? I couldn't make that up from your question.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm... I don't want unlock it. Just screen is turn on, I show default lockscreen.

Comment: Then you should call the lockscreen function and afterwards use the powermanager to show the screen, I added PowerManager code to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I won't it. I try this function many time but I didn't. Your help is very useful to me.